# Count how many times a character appears with another character

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, count

I am attempting to create a matrix display of how many times a character (Ex: A) appears in a cell with another character (Ex: B).

I started down the path of using COUNTIF but I couldn't get the logic to work and scrapped it.

Here is my sheet I am working off of:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jgIrQK_SbwVmMShwouFUy4RVRD0DkkEik9KYVUNrlJ8/edit?usp=sharing

The data range is $B$2:$C$6

How can I count the number of times A occurs in the same cell as B? And then reproduce that formula across the whole matrix to look for how many times A occurs in the same cell as C through T?

Does my explanation of my goal make sense? Is what I want to do possible in sheets?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$C$6,"*A*",$B$2:$C$6,"*B*")
```

Or with Cell references:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$C$6,"*" & K$7 & "*",$B$2:$C$6,"*" & $J8 & "*")
```

Comment: Thanks Scott! You rock!